# JAVA: if without curly brackets, and relation to continue

Tags: java, syntax, decompiler

I have the following java code fragment

```
while (condition1){
    switch (someinteger){
        case 1:
            if(condition2) continue;
            // other stuff here
            break;
        // other cases here
    }
}
```

All is fine. When I generate a class file and then decompile it using a free tool (JD-gui), I get back the following code.

```
while (condition1){
    switch (someinteger){
        case 1:
            if(!condition2);
            // other stuff here
            break;
        // other cases here
    }
}
```

So it changes `if(condition2) continue;` to `if(!condition2);`
I could not find any info on the other if statement (without braces). 
Can anyone explain the logic here? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I did some more tests and the decompiler does not work correctly.

here is the code before:

```
public void strip(InputStreamReader f1, OutputStreamWriter f2) throws IOException{
    int commentON=0, quoteON=0;
    int b1;
    while ((b1 = f1.read()) != -1){
        switch ((char) b1){
            case '\\':
                    if (commentON==0){
                            quoteON = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                    continue;
            case '\n':
                    if (commentON>0){ commentON=0; continue; }
                    break;
            case '%':
                    if (commentON>0) continue;
                    if (quoteON>0) { quoteON=0; break; }
                    commentON=2;
                    continue;
            default:
                    if (commentON>0) continue;
                    if (quoteON>0) quoteON=0;
                    break;
        }
        f2.write(b1);
    }
}
```

here is the decompiled code

```
public void strip(InputStreamReader f1, OutputStreamWriter f2) throws IOException
{
int commentON = 0; int quoteON = 0;

while ((b1 = f1.read()) != -1)
{
  int b1;
  switch ((char)b1)
  {
  case '\\':
    if (commentON == 0);
    quoteON = 1;
    break;
  case '\n':
    if (commentON <= 0) break label109; commentON = 0; break;
  case '%':
    if (commentON <= 0);
    if (quoteON > 0) { quoteON = 0; break label109: }
    commentON = 2;
    break;
  }
  if (commentON <= 0);
  if (quoteON > 0) quoteON = 0;

  label109: f2.write(b1);
}
}
```

sorry for bothering everyone. :P
I'll try to delete this question if I can.

Comment: BTW... im not arguing about the correctness of the decompiled code. I'm just surprised that `if(condition2) continue;` is the same as `if(!condition2);` 
Does this mean that execution automatically continues from the correct point (in this case, the beginning of `while` loop)?

Comment: Is it just me or are they not logically the same.

In the first set of code if `condition1 = true` and `someInteger = 1` and `condition2 = true` then
`// other stuff here` *will not* be executed.

But in the second code block with the same conditions `// other stuff here` *will* be executed.

Comment: @David - I'm with you, I don't see it.

Comment: My guess is that it was compiled without anything in the `// other stuff here` part. Which would make it logically correct - only the OP's interpretation of it being wrong (the `// other stuff here` belonging in the "then" part of the conditional)

Comment: @Anon: - Yeah I think you're right.

Comment: if(anything); is a no-op unless "anything" has side-effects.  are you sure there is a semi-colon at the end and not braces?

Comment: yes it does not seem correct to me either. Somehow the code runs correctly. It is possible my particular example does not get affected by it. I'll make some tests with different examples and get back.

Comment: @amit, you'd be better off using the output of javap to see what the compiler is actually doing, if you don't mind having to figure out how to read bytecode. The decompiler is really just guessing.

Comment: I've never seen a named-break work like that either.  I had thought that a label needed to be infront of a statementment (or basic block) that then contained the break on that label.  Not a C-like downward jump like that (to label109).  Was this changed after 1.2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is near impossible for decompilers reconstruct your original syntax as they are working off the compiler's interpretation of your code.

you write java code, which gets compiled to byte code by the java compiler.

a decompiler then attempts to create java code from the byte code.

since the two code fragments are logically the same, the decompiler has done it's job.

**EDIT (saw your comment):**

actually, it's quite possible (and this is pretty common) that the decompiler has made an error.

the statement `if(!condition2);` essentially has no effect whatsoever (provided condition2 is indeed a boolean and not pseudo code).

therefore your first `//other stuff here` would be processed regardless of `condition2` in the decompiled version.

are you sure the decompiled code works correctly?

Comment: It is possible that the OP assumed `//other stuff here` would still appear there. See @Anon's comment to question.

Comment: i agree, either that or the de-compiler errored, which in my experience is quite common although i haven't used the de-compiler he mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

An if statement with no body ("without curly braces") is simply an empty if statement that executes no code.

Comment: Wrong - it's an if statement that executes the next line of code if the condition is true or skips it if it's false...

Comment: @Basic: True in general, but you're taking my answer out of context; the OP used the phrase "without curly braces" to denote the statement `if(!condition2);`.

Answer (score 0):

It is an alternative/canonical representation of the same logic. Decompilers don't preserve the code.